# jQuery closest (closest that hasClass when elements have multiple classes)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't understand how I will get the jQuery "closest" to work when elements have multiple classes.

The code below alerts "DIV" but I would like it to alert "SPAN" since "SPAN" is the first element (self or parent) that has the class "box".

So, how can I do this?

```
<div class="box">
    <span class="red box">
        <a class="elem" />
    </span>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    var nodeName = $('.elem').closest('.box').prop('nodeName');
});
```

jquery: 1.11.2

Comment: if you write var nodeName = $('.elem').closest('.red.box').prop('nodeName'); then span will alert

Comment: can you reproduce it in fiddle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem lies in how you have written your HTML.

If you close the `<a>`tag, everything works fine ([see fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6fe3ahf8/)):

```
<div class="box">
    <span class="box">
        <a class="elem"></a>
    </span>
</div>
```

With your code, jQuery sees the `<span>` and `<a>`as siblings, because in HTML5 there are no "self-closing" elements, but just elements with no closing tag, like `<br>`.

Comment: You are correct sir, thank you. I can't mark your answer as "answer" yet. Must wait a few minutes.